# Branch point of $\frac{\sin\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{z}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points

> Show that $z=0$ is not a branch point for the function $f(z)= \frac{\sin\sqrt{z}}{\sqrt{z}}$. Is it a removable singularity?
>
> **Definition**- a branch point of a multi-valued function is a point such that the function is discontinuous when going around an arbitrarily small circuit around this point.

I have no idea how to prove the first part. For the second part, I am not sure if the $lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin z}{z} = 1$, can be applied and hence can we conclude if its a removable singularity? Because I think as $z\to 0$, $$f(z)\to \frac{\sin(e^{\frac{\iota\theta}{2}})}{e^{\frac{\iota\theta}{2}}}$$ would not exist. I have assumed $\sqrt{z}:=\frac{1}{2}(\log(|z|)+ \arg(z))$ where $0\leq \arg(z)<2\pi$

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The Maclaurin series of $\sin$ can be of great help.

Comment: When you cross the branch cut of $\sqrt{z}$, $\sqrt{z}$ picks up an minus sign. Since $\sin(.)$ is an odd function, $\sin\sqrt{z}$ picks up another minus sign and these two minus signs cancel each other!

Comment: No branch points here - check out the Taylor expansion.